# EPPlus - group row

Tags: excel, grouping, epplus

EPPlus 4.0.4.0 how to set the line grouping?
I have to get as attached photo.
Thank you!

Settings:

[image]

Comment: Could you post some code with what you have tried so far?  Not 100% sure what you are trying to do but see if this post helps at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760210/how-to-group-rows-columns-in-epplus/32763961#32763961

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I did not find what I need in the link above. Use the codide to generate the grouping. I do not know how to set the ortinamento on the first line!
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know Italian but assuming you mean the option for "Summary Rows Below Details" here is how you turn it on for a `Worksheet`:

```cs
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileinfo))
{
    var workbook = package.Workbook;
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();
    worksheet.OutLineSummaryBelow = true;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I wanted . Thanks and forgive my English