# How to set multi level collapsible outlines using EPPlus

Tags: epplus

I was looking at the [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760210/how-to-group-rows-columns-in-epplus) to create a multi level collapsible grouping in Excel using EPPlus, but I am not able to create a inner group within an existing group.
Please see the example file I am using here[image]

It seems, I need to set the OutlineLevel for Row 14- 18 twice, first to set them at level 3 and also again to set them at level 2 as part of the larger group (Row 10 - 27), and it's only taking the level 2 value, not showing the inner level.[image]

Let me know if there is a way to achieve it using EPPlus.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this if you think of creating outer level first, then create inner level (using C#).

```cs
// 0. populate with basic data
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "outside";    //  | outside |        |
worksheet.Cells[2, 2].Value = "inside";     //  |         | inside |
worksheet.Cells[3, 1].Value = "outside";    //  | outside |        |

// 1. outter level
for(int i=1; i<=3; i++)
{
    worksheet.Row(i).OutlineLevel = 1;
    worksheet.Row(i).Collapsed = true;
}

// 2. inner level
worksheet.Row(2).OutlineLevel = 2;
worksheet.Row(2).Collapsed = true;
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]